# Creating Tables with PrettyTable Library - the columns are not alligend

Tags: python-3.x, alignment, prettytable

I use a very simple code for creating a table using prettytable library. The columns are not aligned (see result below). Why it is happening?

[image]

Comment: Mamad Reza, did you test your code on the terminal (not IDE) ;) [link](https://imgur.com/a/rBYMV7m)?

Comment: Dear A D,  it works in terminal. But I wanted to know why it is not working in IDLE?

Comment: Well, I guess it can be related to the font that your IDE uses! you can use `t.align["'Name'"] = "r"` (not a big change) or formatting , i. e. `f"{24:>10}"`.  If you can use any other third-party library in your project, you might consider using [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

Comment: Tabulate library also shows some disalignment, but it works better. The idea with fonts was great. I changed the fonts to simpler one and now it looks much better. thanx